# ImportError: cannot import name 'amp' from 'apex' (unknown location) (Jupyter lab)

Tags: python-3.x, torch

When I was trying to run huggingface models  on Jupyterlab I faced this problem

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, DataCollatorForSeq2Seq, Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer


ImportError: cannot import name 'amp' from 'apex' (unknown location)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. After installing apex, the folder site-packages/apex is under a folder called apex-0.1-py3.8.egg. I moved the folder apex and EGG-INFO out of the apex-0.1-py3.8.egg folder and the issue was solved.